# Define tuple error: expected ',' seperator

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Here's the code:

```
var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {

        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
        //Error: expected ',' seperator
        //Error: expected pattern

            switch self {

            //Three cases here. 

            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        //Error: use of unresolved identifier 'path'
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        //Error: use of unresolved identifier 'parameters' 
    }
```

There are several errors shown, but I think all are caused by the same problem.
Code is upgraded to Swift 2.

Comment: Could be the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672279/error-after-updating-the-xcode-to-7-0. Try `let (path, parameters) : (String : [String: AnyObject]) = ...`

Comment: Oh great! It is the same problem. Thank you!