# Swift confusing "unresolved identifier" in for loop

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

See the following straightforward code:

```
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json! {
    var aUser = User(json: subJson) # "Use of unresolved identifier 'subJson'"
    users.append(aUser)
}
```

Why does it say subJson is unresolved?  I'm defining it in the for loop declaration...  This just started as of Swift 2.0 by the way.

Comment: Essentially the same problem as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672279/error-after-updating-the-xcode-to-7-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we declare the type of iterators in a for loop has changed in Swift 2.

Now we have to declare the tuple of variables and their type separated by `:` like this:

```
for (index, subJson):(String, JSON) in json! {
   var aUser = User(json: subJson)
   users.append(aUser)
}
```